# Echoing time from now and one hour later

Tags: php, centos

Here I have set the my Centos time Zone.> sudo hwclock – show

```
Tue 04 Feb 2014 10:23:10 AM AFT  -0.596389 seconds
asia/kabul
```

Now on PHP I want to echo from **10:23:10 AM to 11:23:10 AM**

Here I have set my code for the echoing.

```
<? echo (date('G', time())+5) ;
echo(':00 To ');
echo (date('G', time())+6);
echo(':00');  ?>
```

Now as result of my above echoing PHP code I get the **result** of

```
15:00 To 16:00
```

But instead I want to get the echo of below or as what ever my HTTP server time is from NOW to 1 hour next.

```
10:23:10 AM to 11:23:10 AM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the time and then print the date.

```
echo date('G',time()+3600);
```

time() returns number of seconds since the unix epoch, then you add 3600 seconds for 1 hour and you use that in your date.

Comment: as a result I get my next hour which is 11, only 11

Comment: this: 10:23:10 AM to 11:23:10 AM

would be echo date("h:i:s A",time()) . ' to ' . date("h:i:s A",time()+3600);

Answer (score 2):

`echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('now')), ' to ', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 hour'));`

For date format, please read: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

For your format:

```
echo date('h:i:s A', strtotime('now')), ' to ', date('h:i:s A', strtotime('+1 hour'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try `strtotime()`. Something like this:

```
echo date('h:i:s A'), ' to ', date('h:i:s A', strtotime('+1 hour'));
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `explode` function.

```
<?PHP    
$time = date('G:i:s');
$eTime = explode(':', $time);
$timePlusOneHour = $eTime+1 . ":{$eTime[1]}:{$eTime[2]}";
echo $time . " To " . $timePlusOneHour;
```

Comment: `H` means 00 ~ 23, `$timePlusOneHour = $eTime+1` will become `23:00:00 to 24:00:00`

Comment: here I get blank, dear

Comment: This is a lot more complicated and error prone than it needs to be.